# Moving one hard disc from one MacBook to other one

Tags: ssd, macbook, time-machine, migration

I'd like to move my 512 gb sad from my old macbook to the new one. But I am not sure I'd face issues with it ?

Backing up the entire one with time machine and restoring to the new one is quite straight forward but I'd like to know if it works with the scenario I told.

Just remove the sad from old one and plug in to the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have transferred one hdd from a macbook pro to another without issue. Keeping in mind that as long as neither of the MacBooks are retina, then you should not have a problem, the macbook picks up the new drive perfectly fine and boots fine. As you mentioned, using time machine is very helpful and I would feel confident to do so again.

The reason behind the retina versions is that they do not use normal hdd or ssd's and a retinas ssd cannot be replaced unless replacing with another Apple official ssd 'card'

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'll give it a try and if it passes I'm gonna set this as answer. thanks.

Comment: :D Perfect, glad I would help